# Emacs/ESS/Org hangs/spins on yank

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, ess, yank

I have the following Emacs org buffer that I'm editing:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R
regimes <- read.spreadsheet(wlda, 3) %>%
    within({
        TurbineID <- paste(Site, Turbine)
        Date.of.Change.of.Risk.Level <- convert.excel.date(Date.of.Change.of.Risk.Level)
        Non.REA <- Non.REA=="Yes"  # Convert to boolean & foo
        X9 <- X10 <- NULL # Trailing columns
    }) %>%
    group_by(Site, Turbine) %>%
    mutate(
        Curtailment.Level.Before = na.locf(Curtailment.Level.Before),
        Curtailment.Level.After  = na.locf(Curtailment.Level.After, fromLast=TRUE)
    )
#+END_SRC
```

Syntax highlighting (`font-lock-mode`) is enabled in this buffer.

I hit <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to start a new R session.

If I then go back to the Org buffer, highlight all the code in the code block, hit <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to grab it, and then move to the R session buffer and yank it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>, which runs `ess-yank`), Emacs immediately freezes and consumes 100% CPU.  None of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, or anything else I've tried will interrupt it, I have to actually kill the Emacs process from a shell.

Note that I have *not* actually tried to execute the R code at this point, it's just been yanked (pasted) into the ESS console buffer.

Anyone help with some debugging here?

## My setup:

- Emacs 24.5.1, installed using homebrew
- OS X 10.10.5
- Org-mode 8.3.2, installed using `org-plus-contrib` 20151228 from ELPA
- ESS 15.09-2, installed from ELPA 20151217.544

This behavior happens whether I'm using the OS X `.app` or running in a terminal.

## Update

I think this has something to do with syntax highlighting.  If I run `font-lock-mode` to turn off highlighting in my org buffer before I grab the text, the problem disappears.  I simplified the example above to reflect this.

## Update 2

I triggered this problem in the way described above, then I hit the process with a `SIGUSR2` signal and got the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--beginning evaluation of function call form:
* (byte-code "r^Hq\210\302      !\210)\302\207" [buffer table set-syntax-table] 2)
  font-lock-default-fontify-region(802 1304 nil)
  inferior-ess-fontify-region(802 1304 nil)
  font-lock-fontify-region(802 1304)
  run-hook-with-args(font-lock-fontify-region 802 1304)
  #[0 "\302\303\300\242\301\242#\207" [(802) (1304) run-hook-with-args jit-lock-functions] 4 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  funcall(#[0 "\302\303\300\242\301\242#\207" [(802) (1304) run-hook-with-args jit-lock-functions] 4 "\n\n(fn)"])
  jit-lock-fontify-now(802 1302)
  jit-lock-function(802)
  redisplay_internal\ \(C\ function\)()
```

I notice that the docs of `byte-code` say "If the third argument is incorrect, Emacs may crash."  In this case, the third argument (`MAXDEPTH`) is passed as 2, perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: When I do C-c C-c in the first block, it returns the value "2" but does not start a persistent R session. When I start an R session and copy the second block over, I get an error: "could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Yes, if you replace `1+1` by  `5%>%2` and call `C-c C-c` you also get `could not find function "%>%`. I could reproduce your problem. It is not emacs that hangs but R. One time I killed R and sent emacs a QUIT signal per `pkill -QUIT emacs`. The result was that I got `R aborted` in the emacs R-shell buffer. But this does not always work. Sometimes emacs just quits also on `pkill -QUIT emacs`. But, my environment is special with regard of kill. I am working under cygwin.

Comment: Those results mean you can't duplicate the problem.  In my scenario R is definitely never getting invoked (because yanking into a buffer doesn't run R), so it never has a chance to decide whether `%>%` is defined or not.  In my "full" orgmode file all that stuff is defined, including the functions being called, variables referenced, etc. and the problem is the same.

Comment: @Tyler - Perhaps you have to run `C-c C-c` in the header section first to make the config take effect.

Comment: Ok. It works now, and returns the `could not find function` error where you report Emacs hanging.

Comment: So I guess neither of you have the issue - what versions of Emacs/ESS are you using?  I think those are the critical pieces.

Comment: Emacs 25.0.50.2, compiled from source. ESS 15.09-2 from ELPA 20151217.544. R 3.2.3. org 8.3.2 from ELPA.

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/123. I had this problem before on both OSX and Ubuntu machines and couldn't find a solution. But there is a better way than copy/past for sending the code to R process, which don't have this hang problem.